# r: how to insert a value into a specific pattern

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to add a special character to a series of values. But I don't know how.

Here is the original input:

```
chemical <- "200mL of Ac2O3, 3.5mml of AgBF4, 10.0ml of AgBr, 100ml of AgCl3Cu2"
```

And I want:

```
"200mL of Ac~2~O~3~, 3.5mml of AgBF~4~, 10.0ml of AgBr, 100ml of AgCl~3~Cu~2~"
```

Basically, I am adding a "~" before and after anytime there is a number in the chemical formula in the original data.

I was trying to use gsub but I am not sure how I am supposed to tell R to find just those numbers in a chemical formula and then do the insertion.

Does anyone have a thought on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This succeeds. Whether it will deliver from a more varied case might be an issue:

```
gsub("([^ [:digit:].])([[:digit:]])", "\\1~\\2~", chemical)
#[1] "200mL of Ac~2~O~3~, 3.5mml of AgBF~4~, 10.0ml of AgBr, 100ml of AgCl~3~Cu~2~"
```

Logic is to match a pairing of a {non-digit,non-space, non-decimal point} character followed by a digit and put a tilde flanking hte digit. If the size of the "number" could ever exceeds 9 then you would want to put a quantified after the digit: "[[:digit:]]{1, 30}" perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

```
gsub("(?<=[A-Za-z])([0-9])","~\\1~",chemical,perl = T)
[1] "200mL of Ac~2~O~3~, 3.5mml of AgBF~4~, 10.0ml of AgBr, 100ml of AgCl~3~Cu~2~"
```

Here you need to use the positive lookback syntax `?<=` to specify that you want your numbers to be preceded by letters, upper case or lower case `[A-z]`. You use parentheses for the number to make a capture group, that you call with `\1`, ecsaped with `\` in your replacement: `~\\1~`. The `perl = T` is there to allow for the positive lookback syntax

Comment: [`[A-z]` does not only match letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970)

Comment: Safer might be `[A-Za-z]` although `[:alpha:]` might have some locale specific extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @denis answer but without using the perl syntax:

`gsub("([A-Za-z])([0-9]+)","\\1~\\2~",chemical)`

(corrected per @Wiktor correct comment)

Comment: [`[A-z]` does not only match letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970)

Answer (score 1):

An option is to `strsplit` on `space` and then replace `digits` in words starting with `character` with `~\\1~`:

```
chemical <- "200mL of Ac2O3, 3.5mml of AgBF4, 10.0ml of AgBr, 100ml of AgCl3Cu2"


a <- strsplit(chemical, split = " ")[[1]]

paste0(ifelse(grepl("^[a-zA-Z].*", a),gsub("(\\d)","~\\1~", a),a),collapse = " ")
#[1] "200mL of Ac~2~O~3~, 3.5mml of AgBF~4~, 10.0ml of AgBr, 100ml of AgCl~3~Cu~2~"
```

Comment: that's a complicated way to do positive lookback, but it's clever

Comment: @denis I know. You were quick in providing solution with forward lookup. Hence I had to change my solution. You got an smart answer.